# How to fill an std::vector of complex doubles from an std::vector of real doubles

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, complex-numbers

I'm working on a math code, that heavily relies on convolution via inplace-FFT of real data.

Since my data is real up until it enters the convolution and will be real right when the convolution is done, I use `std::vector<double>` everywhere.

So inside my convolution, I have to copy my real data into my complex data. I have not found any way to do this with `std::fill()` or any other method more sophisticated than looping over all entries.

In addition: When measuring the time taken when using raw pointers vs. `unique_ptr` vs. `std::vector` the first one wins with about half the time taken, with many `get()` operations through the wrappers. 
Is my compiler missing some optimization or do I have to go with raw pointers and the hassle of memory?

Working Example: I can not test this right now, but I have old times heavily supporting my claim. These timing were made by building the solution with Visual Studio  Community 2015 by using (Build Solution) from Build-Dropdown. 
Performance-Analysis shows, much time is spent in getting from wrapper to data.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

void FFT();
void IFFT();

int main() {
    unsigned int N=1024;

    std::vector<double> real;
    real.resize(N);
    std::vector<double> imag;
    imag.resize(N);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        real[i] = i;
        imag[i] = i;
    }

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::complex<double> I = std::complex<double> (0, 1);
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> data;
    data.resize(2048);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        data[i] = real[i] + I*imag[i];
    }
    FFT();

    data[0] = 0.25*I*(conj(data[0] * data[0]) - data[0]*data[0]);
    for (unsigned int r = 1; r < 2 * N - r; ++r) {
        std::complex<double> z1 = data[2 * N - r];
        std::complex<double> z2 = data[r];
        std::complex<double> res = 0.25*I*(conj(z1 * z1) - z2*z2);
        data[r]=res;
        data[2*N - r]= conj(res);
    }
    IFFT();

    std::vector<double> result;
    result.resize(2 * N);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 * N; ++i) {
        result[i] = data[i].real();
    }

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
}
```

Comment: "Is my compiler missing some optimization or do I have to go with raw pointers and the hassle of memory?" Which compiler are you using? Which flags?

Comment: I'm working on a minimal example. Have to make one up from scratch, since copying from all other the project is a mess!

Answer (score 2):

> I have not found any way to do this with std::fill or any other method more sophisticated than looping over all entries.

Just use `std::transform` with lambda:

```
std::vector<double> a{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
std::vector<double> b{ 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 };
std::vector<std::complex<double>> cvec( a.size() );
std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), cvec.begin(), []( double da, double db ) {
    return std::complex<double>( da, db );
} );
```

you have to make sure that `b` and `cvec` at least as big as `a`, though for `cvec` you can use `std::back_inserter` but that maybe slightly slower if you do not call reserve for it.

Comment: Wouldn't std::copy work, since there is an implicit conversion? Or even vector::insert?

Comment: @MarcGlisse this is just an example, I am not sure that OP uses `std::complex` and if not if that class has implicit ctor.

Comment: I have two vectors a and b. I want vector c, so that c[n]=a[n]+i*b[n] with(i=sqrt(-1)). This is not given here.

Comment: @Laray my telepathy machine is broken today, here is given what you asked for, not what you had in mind. Though updated answer for your new request

Comment: Sorry, I redrafted the Question multiple times. It was in there before I erased something and forgot to put it back in.

Comment: Thank you, that could help me! But another request: the sizes are (in some cases) size(a)=n, size(b)=n+1 and size(c)=2n. Is there a good way then?